# dynamically load pages from Homepage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu for user to select which page they want to look at on my homepage. please can anyone show me how to load a page in javascript once a user selects a particular option from the menu? I want the page to be loaded in a div or groupbox but the menu list should be static for all pages. 
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: So you want to use JavaScript to reinvent links **and** frames?

Comment: No, he's just asking how to implement both at the same time using JavaScript.

Comment: hi people, actually I want to know how to this using javascript. i am not good with javascript, am a learner but I believe this can be achieved using jscript. any ideas pleaes?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would like to take a look at jQuery tabs:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

Hope this helps!
N.S.

Answer (score 0):

I guess having the same menu on all your pages should suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but that is actually what am trying to avoid. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this? Everybody's doing it. If you really don't want this, just create a page and ajax-load your content when people click on a menu. Or load everything at once, and do some nice effect (easy with jQuery, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776028/dynamically-load-pages-from-homepage/6776067#6776067) to switch between divs.